# How to link a user to a group where the user can view only the posts from other users in that group in Django

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models, foreign-keys

I have a class full of students. Within the class there are many groups of students. I want the students in each group to only be able to view the posts of the students in their group.

I am not sure whether to make the groups via the django admin, or to make a model called class_group. I would like to be able to add student to one of these groups.

I don't know how I would use the model route, because I am not sure of how to give a user a foreign-key to a model.

Any advice would help!

Answer (score 1):

The groups from django's builtin authentication backend are groups of permissions. You assign users to that group as a quick way to give them permissions.

That means you will need a separate model `StudentGroup` for the groups of students.
Obviously, you also need a model `Student` for the individual students.
Assuming one student can have many groups, model `Student` has a `ManyToManyField` to `StudentGroup`. Let's call that field `groups`.

The model should also have a `ForeignKey` to the builtin `User` model: explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).
The `Post` model should contain a `ForeignKey` back to `Student` (let's call it `author`) so that each `Post` can have only one author.
Then you can get all allowed posts with query such as this:

```
student_groups = current_user.groups.all() # all groups of the current user
# filter for posts whose author shares some of the groups of the current user
Post.objects.filter(author__groups__in=student_groups)
```